# how to assign a unique id to each new user in a certain format?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter-3

I have a form and I can add new users to the admin panel and I would like to generate unique id for each of them with this format H00001 , H00002, H00003 , and so on.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: I have only tried uniqid(),

Comment: Can you edit the question with a [mcve] of your code so far?

Comment: You can always use auto-incremented id and then glue your `Hxxx` whatever at the point where you pull the user out. There's literally no need to go with custom solution because you can be 100% sure it will be completely wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It just my try . i don't know how far it work and logic is correct or not . **experts please correct me if anything wrong**

Create the table with auto increment

```
create table idgenerater(id int not null autoincrement,
                         insert_date datetime default timestamp
                         );
```

Each new user registration  insert record in `idgenerater` and get the last inserted id and store it into your registration table using `str_pad` like this

`str_pad` is Pad to the given string to your string

```
    <?php

    $id='10'; //GOT ID FROM TABLE 

    $ss = str_pad($id,4,0,STR_PAD_LEFT);

    echo "H".$ss;

    ?>
```

**output:**

```
H0010
```

Comment: thxx @jYothl i will go through it

Comment: I'm not an expert but your solution is the only possible correct solution so have +1 from me. OP should accept this as an answer.

Comment: thanks for the appreciation @Mjh

Answer (score -1):

If you want to do on server side (php), you can use the library which i have created. Please check this link

https://www.phpclasses.org/package/9822-PHP-Generate-unique-identifier-strings.html

Comment: i will check it out thx

Comment: This is not an answer at all.

Comment: why it was not @Mjh? @Mikethetechy needs that functionality only

Comment: He asks how to generate unique identifiers, you give him a link to some class which you can't even see unless you're a member of that (bad) site. How's that answering the question? It's questionable if your class even generates anything unique, which is difficult to determine as the code isn't public.